# Linux kernel functions and kernel module development

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am about to write my first kernel module for `Linux ubuntu 3.8.0-29-generic`

I do not have man 9 section for kernel functions (e.g. kmalloc, kfree...)
Neither can I see some function definitions in `/usr/include`, but rather in `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-53/include/linux`. How do I include headers in my code in this case?

I suspect there might be something like `apt-get install kernel-devel` that would solve all these issues at once, but I can't find one.

Also a link to a good introduction to kernel module writing would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use the Synaptic Package Manager, and search for "dev" packages.

Comment: Check this link - http://askubuntu.com/questions/359032/unable-to-locate-package-linux-kernel-devel

Comment: http://www.opensourceforu.com/2010/12/writing-your-first-linux-driver/

Comment: Correct answer was: apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use kernel version 3.8.0, why do you have the headers of 3.2.0? You can download an extra source tree with the 3.8.0 and compile a new kernel without replacing the existing 3.2.0.

any way, lets work on the existing 3.2.0.

- First, make sure the kernel the system is running is the same version
  as the headers directory you've mentioned.

  Check your system kernel version using:

  $ uname -r

  And see that you get 3.2.0. This means that when you include
  (#include) kernel header files in your program, they will be the ones
  in `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-53/include/linux`.
- Second, installing man section 9: For that you will need to download the kernel source code. Choose the version you want from https://www.kernel.org/ and download it to your home directory. In that source directory execute:

  $ sudo apt-get install xmlto

  $ make mandocs

  $ sudo make installmandocs

Comment: kernel.org doesn't have my version (3.13.0-24). is there a way to do that with apt-get source?

Comment: I think you can download it from here http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-source-3.13.0

Comment: it happened be much easier with apt-get (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel). And I will accept your answer as it helped me with those mandocs makes :-)